# How to put the content of a JDom document into a File object?

Tags: java, xml, jdom

if I have a **JDom Document** as this one:

```
Document configDocument = configHelper.getConfigDocument();
```

What can I do to put its content into a File object?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

Use an [XMLOutputer](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html#output%28org.jdom2.Document,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) with a [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html).